# MiKTeX 2.9 portable -- Unavailable to complete the update

Tags: errors, miktex

I have received several errors with MiKTeX 2.9, being portable or standard install, in which some files related to configuration, does not work well.

In my laptop (Win XP, spanish), the user's configuration directory, has an accented character. Example: ..\djnavas\Configuración local\Datos de programa\MiXTeX\
and the standard install created a directory with the name changed rewriting the accented character, like in "Configuraci%A5n local" (not necessarily equal as in my machine).

In my office, I use portable MiKTeX from an USB.  The program works, but have the difficulty that can't rebuild the formats after pressing the button "Update Formats".

The error report I copied, is:

> MiKTeX Problem Report Message: Windows
>   API error 5: Acceso denegado.
>
> Data:  Source:
>   Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winProcess.cpp
>   Line: 810

Acceso denegado means, "access denied".

This problem happened after an update of packages from a mirror, through the web.

I hope to read some ideas of what to do.

Comment: The same problem occurs here. could you tell me how to solve this same exact problem or attach the link to download the update. I could not find it.

Comment: The dante-repository in germany has already the update from 15.12. So you can use this.

Comment: @xiegema: Welcome! If you've got a question, then you should ask it in a new post. Please do this with the "Ask Question" link.

Comment: well I have the 28 February 2011 miktex-runtime-bin, on a clean install as of today 1 March 2011, and I get this error, "funnily" enough I don't get the problem on my laptop which I update at the same time with the same programs and options... my desktop runs windows enterprise 7-32bits while my laptop runs windows pro 7-64bits...

Comment: @pat: Welcome to tex.sx! Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a bug report with an "windows API 5" error. The comments say that the update of today (15.12.2010) of miktex-runtime-bin has solved the problem. (In case the update isn't yet in your mirror: Christian wrote that he has set up a temporary mirror ctan.miktex.org where you can get the update.)

Comment: Many thanks. I will try. The mirrors have a date of first days of december and only four were available.

Comment: I had only two mirrors yesterday. Today there are more. Probably Christian disconnected the other to avoid that the broken package spread.